# Div layout issues

Tags: html, css

I am having a difficult time getting the right  positional css for a layout with a main header div, a left side that holds an image and a right side that has two pieces on top of each other. The HTML and CSS follow, I removed all my non essential css and the positional css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >

<html lang="en"">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="header">

<div id="hdrleft">
<div class="hdrimage">
</div>
</div>
    <div id="hdrright">
    <div class="logindisplay">
    </div>
    <div class="logotransitions">
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

```css
#header{
width:800px;
height:250px;
}
#hdrleft{
height:240px;
width:540px;
}
.hdrimage
{
display:inline;
float:left;
height:230px;
width:520px;
background-color:green;
}

#hdrright
{

width:240px;
padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
}

.logindisplay 
{
display:inline;
float:right;
height:240px;
height:80px;
width:240px;    
background-color:red;
}

.logotransitions 
{
 display:inline;
float:right;
height:240px;
height:155px;
width:240px;    
background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: It's a bit difficult to see the issue. As it is, all of your elements are blank. It wouldn't be a problem if you provided all of your CSS and the relevant portion of your HTML (without content removed) at a service like jsfiddle.

Comment: i took all the content out for brevity. You can put a background color in each div for visual. Im not familiar with usage of jsfiddle

Comment: FWI: The padding have a colon `:` instead of a semicolon `;` at it's end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `#hdrleft` and `#hdrleft` to add the float attribute to break the flow:

```
#hdrleft {
    height:240px;
    width:740px;
    float: left;
}
#hdrright {
    height:240px;
    width:240px;
    /* padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px; //Add to child elements as margin instead. */
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: This won't work unless the `padding` on `#hdrright` is removed as well because the two widths will overflow the `#header`. See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DMuHp/1/) where the padding has been commented out.

Comment: Roddy. I've made some of those adjustments bu they still do not display straight across together the right side top edge is much lower than the left side top edge

Comment: @dinotom - Your `#header` is too narrow and you need to put the `float: left` on the `#hdrleft`, not on the `.hdrimage`. See [the updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qt2ah/7/).

Comment: thanks for the help Roddy i have it now.....how do I acknowledge your answer since its in comments?

Comment: @dinotom Just set Krycke's answer as the answer and +1 the helpful comment. He did all the work, really.